# xml_node<wchar_t> I'm using rapid xml to print the XML document to a file

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

I'm trying to print a xml to a file using `rapidxml` . 
But the values are in `wstring`. So i've used templated version of it by attaching 
xml_node `wchar_t` instead of specialization of the xml_node .
But When i'm doing this:

```
std::string xml_as_string;
rapidxml::print<std::string,wchar_t>(std::back_inserter(xml_as_string), doc); ///i'm not very sure of this line . This line only gives a error 
// i tried this   "rapidxml::print<t>" also i'm getting an error .

//Save to file
std::ofstream file_stored("C:\\Logs\\file_stored.xml");
file_stored << doc;
file_stored.close();
doc.clear();
```

It throws a error stating Error:

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'rapidxml::xml_document<Ch>' (or there is no acceptable conversion).
```

Any help will be appreciated . thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to explicitly specify the template arguments here:

```
rapidxml::print<std::string,wchar_t>(std::back_inserter(xml_as_string), doc);
```

you almost certainly make a mistake. The function is supposed to work with the help of automatic template arg detection like this.

```
rapidxml::xml_node<wchar_t> doc(...); // Do some init here
std::wstring xml_as_string;

rapidxml::print(std::back_inserter(xml_as_string), doc);
```

The point is that both args have to be wchar_t based otherwise the templated function would not match. So in the first step you may only output to an `wstring` or `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` to be more specific. Or to an output iterator into a wchar_t output.

If you want to end up with a char based encoding (e.g utf8) you may either use a wchar file output stream and imbue(...) it like:

```
// Not properly checked if this compiles
std::wofstream of("bla.xml");
of.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
of << xml_as_string;
```

or you may use some iconv(...) based solution. You may of course us a file output iterator directly on the wofstream.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with std::wofstream of("bla.xml");
of.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8");
of << xml_as_string;   ....

Comment: @prakashsingh You wrote in your question you want to output to a file and [wofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/wofstream/) is the file abstraction that accepts wchar_t. The way it is mapped onto char i.e latin1,utf8 etc..  is changed via imbue.

Comment: but Rapid XML doesn't support Wofstream. Any way i found a solution ,thanks by the way ... I converted the wstring to char* by writing a function which helped me to the achieve the target. But still main question remains unanswered.. :(